# Finding a value in an interval

Tags: r, cut

Sorry if this is a basic question. Have been trying to figure this out but not being able to.
I have a vector of values called sym.

```
> head(sym)
         [,1]
val  3.652166e-05
val -2.094026e-05
val  4.583950e-05
val  6.570184e-06
val -1.431486e-05
val -5.339604e-06
```

These I put in intervals by using factor on cut function on sym.

> factorx<-factor(cut(sym,breaks=nclass.Sturges(sym)))

```
 [1] (2.82e-05,5.28e-05]  (-2.11e-05,3.55e-06] (2.82e-05,5.28e-05]  (3.55e-06,2.82e-05]    (-2.11e-05,3.55e-06] (-2.11e-05,3.55e-06] 
[7] (-2.11e-05,3.55e-06] (2.82e-05,5.28e-05]  (3.55e-06,2.82e-05]  (7.74e-05,0.000102] 

Levels: (-2.11e-05,3.55e-06] (3.55e-06,2.82e-05] (2.82e-05,5.28e-05] (7.74e-05,0.000102]
```

So clearly, four intervals were created in factorx. Now I have a new value tmp=3.7e-0.6.
My question is how can I find which interval in the above does it belongs to? I tried to use findInterval() but seems it does not work on factors like factorx.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to re-classify new values, it's best to explicitly set the `breaks=` parameter with a vector rather than a size. Not that had those values been in the set originally, you may have had different breaks, and it is possible that your new values may be outside all the levels of your existing data which can be troublesome.

So first, I will generate some sample data.

```
set.seed(18)
x <- runif(50)
```

Now I will show two different way to calculate breaks. Here are `b1()` and `b2()`

```
b1<-function(x, n=nclass.Sturges(x)) {
    #like default cut()
    nb <- as.integer(n + 1)
    dx <- diff(rx <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE))
    if (dx == 0) 
        dx <- abs(rx[1L])
    seq.int(rx[1L] - dx/1000, rx[2L] + dx/1000, 
        length.out = nb)
}
b2<-function(x, n=nclass.Sturges(x)) {
    #like default hist()
    pretty(range(x), n=n)
}
```

So each of these functions will give break points similar to either the default behaviors of `cut()` or `hist()`. Rather than just a single number of breaks, they each return a vector with all the break points explicitly stated. This allows you to use `cut()` to create your factor

```
mybreaks <- b1(x)
factorx <- cut(x,breaks=mybreaks))
```

(Note that's you don't have to wrap `cut()` in `factor()` as `cut()` already returns a factor. Now, if you get new values, you can classify them using `findInterval()` and the special breaks vector you've already prepared

```
nv <- runif(5)
grp <- findInterval(nv,mybreaks)
```

And we can check the results with

```
data.frame(grp=levels(factorx)[grp], x=nv)
#              grp         x
# 1  (0.831,0.969] 0.8769438
# 2 (0.00131,0.14] 0.1188054
# 3  (0.416,0.554] 0.5467373
# 4   (0.14,0.278] 0.2327532
# 5  (0.554,0.693] 0.6022678
```

and everything looks pretty good. In this case, `findInterval()` will tell you which level of the previous factor you created that each item belongs to. It will return 0 if the number is smaller than your previous observations, but it will return the largest category for anything greater than the largest level of `mybreaks`. This behavior is somewhat different that `cut()` which return `NA`. The last group in `cut()` is right-closed where `findInterval` leaves the right-end open.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had resorted to doing something with for loops and such but this is way better!